# Can I tap a tri-fetch land for mana with Chromatic Lantern before it sacrifices itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have [Chromatic Lantern](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chromatic%20Lantern) in play, and play [Brokers Hideout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brokers%20Hideout).

When Broker's Hideout enters the battlefield, it sacrifices itself for its ability.

While that ability is on the stack, can I tap it for mana using the ability it gained from Chromatic Lantern?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, you can use any ability on that fetch land.**

Chromatic Lantern grants the mana ability as a static ability, meaning the Hideout will enter the battlefield with the mana ability already on it. The Hideout's sacrifice ability is a regular triggered ability that uses the stack and can be responded to at instant speed, and you can activate mana abilities at instant speed.

Generally, you can interact with the Hideout with any instant-speed spell or ability. That is the very reason why the Hideout has the "When you do" clause on it - the designers anticipated people interacting with the Hideout before it is actually sacrificed to its own ability.

Comment: And, notably, you can interact with multiple instant speed spells or abilities. One of my friends pulled some crazy shenanigans like this the other day with a Maestros Theater and generated five mana, turned it into an island, and animated it with Genju of the Falls so that it would trigger his half a dozen death triggers when it’s ability finally resolved.

Comment: Something that may be worth including in the answer (or not, I didn't mention Arena in the tags) - MtG: Arena normally auto-passes priority when the tri-fetch land ability triggers, so you need to go into Full Control mode in order to take advantage of this.